# svg.js animating a combined plot and dmove

Tags: javascript, svg.js

I am trying to work out how to animate a combined `plot` and `dmove` in sgv.js.

I was expecting that if I chained a `plot` and `dmove` together after an `animate` that my path would animate from the original geometry to the resulting geometry of `plot` plus `dmove`:

```
myPath.animate().plot('20,20 25,20 25,25 20,25').dmove(100, 100)
```

However the `dmove` does not appear to be relative to `plot` but the original path geometry (myPath).

Using CODEPEN I have tried to [demonstrate this concept](https://codepen.io/McShaman/pen/rKqXEV?editors=0010)

Both `path1` and `path2` start at X:50 and should end at X:200. However the 50 added by the `plot` appear to be ignored.

An alternative I considered was to change the geometry before passing it to the `animate` function:

```
var geometry = new SVG.PointArray('20,20 25,20 25,25 20,25')
geometry.dmove(100, 100)

myPath.animate().plot(geometry)
```

However `PointArray` and `PathArray` classes don't have `dmove` functions.

The svg.js library is extensive and I figure I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is, that `dmove()` is evaluated earlier that you want.
`dmove` just maps to `move` directly after calculating the new coordinates out of the input and bbox. Since your animation is at your starting point at first, the call to dmove sees the "old" bbox and uses this for its relative move.

Calculating your resulting startpoint first (as done in your second try) is the way to go. Path and PointArray might not have a dmove method but they have a bbox method so you can write your own dmove:

```
SVG.extend(SVG.PathArray, SVG.PointArray, {
  dmove: function (dx, dy) {
    var bbox = this.bbox()
    this.move(bbox.x + dx, bbox.y + dy)
    return this
  }
})

new SVG.PointArray('20,20 25,20 25,25 20,25').dmove(100, 100)
```

Ofc you dont need to write a method for this. You can do it by hand, too. But I find adding the functionality direcly is more smooth

Comment: I have tried your recommendation in the past without success. I get an error `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined` from the bbox function at `SVG.parser.poly.setAttribute('points', this.toString())`. There are two typos in your sample above which I have already edited and are awaiting review. If you run it yourself you should get the same error... I hope.

Comment: Just tried it. It works like a charm. Thank you for the edit. I wrote it in a hurry. There is still a missing return which I will add now...   Is your dom loaded when you run this? Because the parser does not exist when the dom is not loaded yet which can lead to the error you are getting.